# Programmatically Rendering an Umbraco Node

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I'm using Umbraco 4.5.2 and I have a node with a number of child nodes. Each child node represents a fragment of HTML that will be rendered in a control. The control loops over all the child nodes and renders them.

For the moment I have a bit of a dirty hack going in order to get the thing going (still fairly new to Umbraco) but I'd rather do this better.

The code I have at the moment looks like this:

```
private string GetItemHtml(Node node)
{
    // Work out the URL of the HTML fragment
    string url = "http://" + Context.Request.Url.Host + 
        ":" + Context.Request.Url.Port + 
                    node.Url;

    // Get the fragment by making a call to the page
    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);
    WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
    using (Stream stream = res.GetResponseStream())
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return result;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it is really rather ugly. I'm hoping there is some way to get this without having to make many HTTP calls, even if it is looping back to the same server - it can't be very efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the API to achieve what you are asking, try looking at the umbraco.library.RenderTemplate method. It accepts two parameters, the first is the id of the node to render and the second is the id of the template to use when rendering the node.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably much easier to build using xslt in umbraco. If you want to do something that is not possible in xslt, you can create a XSLT extension function (implemented in C#, called from XSLT) to do that (see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Umbraco/Create_xslt_exstension_like_umbraco.Library_in_C for more info).

For a sample XSLT that list child pages, see BlogListPosts.xslt in the umbraco blog package:

http://blog4umbraco.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/54177#916032